# How to use the Metaplex `nft-packs` program?

Tags: metaplex

Does anyone have references for how to use the Metaplex `nft-packs` program? Couldn't find anything in the discord. I read through the Readme, but still don't really understand how the program works.

Unsure how the `voucher` works, or how it would get distributed.
Also not sure how the `Request card for redeem` and `Claim` parts work.

For `Request card for redeem`, it says "user calls this instruction to receive index of card which he can redeem".

Then for `Claim`, it says "user call this instruction after they receive a card index from `Request card for redeem`"

Are these two instructions that are suppose to be in one transaction?

https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex-program-library/tree/master/nft-packs/program

Comment: Hi! Did you found something useful? I am trying ti understand this contract too

Answer (score 1):

Metaplex discord does not have any examples of using this Program, I've checked it. I also haven't found any open source examples which utilize it but I might be mistaken there. This answer can also become deprecated if Metaplex resumes their NFT Packs Program development and some OSS examples rise up.

And to answer your first question:

> Does anyone have references for how to use the Metaplex nft-packs program?

No, I don't think anyone has any references willing to share. This can change in the future but I doubt it since the Program hasn't been touched for 9 months

Comment: This isn't really an answer Josip. I would keep it focused at the question at hand.

Comment: Gotcha, I'll edit it and leave only the part which answers the first question